# SDL2_ttf won't run on ios

Tags: c++, ios, sdl

So case is - i downloaded latest SDL2_ttf library, opened XCode-IOS project, included in package, built it without any problem and connected to my project. Everything compiled and ran, but at start my program quits with message in output:

```
apinames 0.1: extract FreeType API names from header files

this program is used to extract the list of public FreeType API
functions. It receives the list of header files as argument and
generates a sorted list of unique identifiers

usage: apinames header1 [options] [header2 ...]

options:   -      : parse the content of stdin, ignore arguments
           -v     : verbose mode, output sent to standard error
           -oFILE : write output to FILE instead of standard output
           -dNAME : indicate DLL file name, 'freetype.dll' by default
           -w     : output .DEF file for Visual C++ and Mingw
           -wB    : output .DEF file for Borland C++
           -wW    : output Watcom Linker Response File
```

in my project i just call TTF_Init() and TTF_Quit(), but it never reaches there.

Comment: I would guess you included `apinames.c` in your project from the tools directory and that main is what is getting run.

Comment: yeap, this is the case. You saved my life ) Thank you